# Couldn't create '.vaadin' folder inside home directory '/': Cannot create directory '/.vaadin'

Tags: vaadin

Using Vaadin version 23.1.17 with Springboot, application running fine in local but while deploying on Env, Build is failing with below error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.1.17:prepare-frontend (default) on project XXMS: Could not execute prepare-frontend goal.: Couldn't create '.vaadin' folder inside home directory '/': Cannot create directory '/.vaadin'. -> [Help 1]

No access on JenkinsFile and if I don't use the goal then getting below error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine project directory for dev mode. Directory '/' does not look like a Maven or Gradle project. Ensure that you have run the prepare-frontend Maven goal, which generates 'flow-build-info.json', prior to deploying your application\n\tat com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.getBaseDirectoryFallback(DevModeInitializer.java:388)\n\tat com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.initDevModeHandler(DevModeInitializer.java:216)\n\tat com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevModeHandlerManagerImpl.initDevModeHandler(DevModeHandlerManagerImpl.java:80)\n\tat com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.failFastContextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:475)\n\tat com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:188)\n\t..

Upgrading from Vaadin 14 to Vaadin 23 and got this error.

Comment: How are you building your production release?
With maven you have someting like: `mvn clean package -Pproduction -Dvaadin.force.production.build=true`

Comment: For me it looks like you are in a wrong directory when building the target release (Probably in /), where your jenkins agent has no write rights